# Calling an API with a websocket

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I have a very simple application that consists of a frontend written in [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and a API written using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). My application polls every x seconds an API endpoint to see if there have been new changes.

This codes gets run every 5 seconds

```
var resource = TokenRestangular.one("jobs", job_id);
resource.then(function (objects) {
    //if we have job completed = true then do something else.                    
},
```

I understand this is a very `old school` way. So my question is, can I use `websockets` to lookup the API resource in AngularJS if so how?

I don't want to have to rewrite a new API so can the API support both REST connections and websockets over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Client side**

Write a service in your angular code that will create a connection to a websocket server. Using a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), you will then update the $scope of you application each time a websocket packet is received. Something like this:

```
    myApp.service( 'WSService', function() {
        this.promise = function ($q) {
            // Create a deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            // Create the WebSocket client pointing to the correct API
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://myIP:myPort/myAPI");
            // Map the messages to action
            ws.onopen = function()  { console.log( "WSService opened"); };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                console.log("onmessage:" + evt);
                deferred.notify(evt);
            };
            ws.onclose = function() { console.log("WSService closed"); };
            // Return the promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
```

then in your controller:

```
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$q','WSService', function($scope, $q, WSService) {
        var promise = WSService.promise($q);

        promise.then(function(evt) { console.log('resolve : ' + evt); }, 
                     function(evt) { console.log('reject : ' + evt); }, 
                     function(evt) {
                         console.log('notify: ' + evt);
                         //Update the scope
                         $scope.myData = evt;
                     }
        );
    }]);
```

**2. Server side**

In front of the API, write a websocket server which will push JSON data with the appropriate format. For example, you can hook to your model signals (save, update) a function that will push the JSON serialization of you model to the client. This way, all updates to your back-end DB will immediately reflect to the client side.

For this, you can use a pre-made package like [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) which seems to be quite popular.

If the data sent by your websocket server match the data in your model and scope, it can qualify to the REST label I guess.